# java print a reverse triagle s with integers

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a java code to print a triangle in reversed order.This is my code.

```
public void drawPatternC(int num) {
 //Loop through the lines from 1 to n
 System.out.println("Pattern .C:" + "\u21B5");
 for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  // printing spaces, 2 at a time from j=1 to j= num-i 
  for (int j = 1; j <= (num - i); j++) {
   System.out.print(" . ");
  }

  //Printing number increamentally from 1 to line number j
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
   System.out.print(j + ". ");
  }
  System.out.println("\u21B5");
 }

}
```

I want the result to look like

```
....1
...21
..321
.4321
```

but am getting a different  i need help

Comment: You have to change the second loop for that check http://ideone.com/g36qa8

Answer (score 0):

You weren't looping the right way with your second loop

Replace

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
```

with

```
for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
```

---

### Correction

```
public void drawPatternC(int num) {         
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= (num - i); j++) {
            System.out.print(" . ");
        }

        //Printing number increamentally from 1 to line number j
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(j+". ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

### Output

```
 .  .  .  . 1. 
 .  .  . 2. 1. 
 .  . 3. 2. 1. 
 . 4. 3. 2. 1. 
5. 4. 3. 2. 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should fix your problem. Its a little more simplified.

```
public void drawPatternC(int num)
{
    for(int i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        for(int j=num;j>i;j--)
        {
            System.out.print("."); 
        }
        for(int k=i;k>0;k--)
        {
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

OUTPUT(when num = 5):

....1

...21

..321

.4321

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in you code

```
public static void drawPatternC(int num) {
    //Loop through the lines from 1 to n
    System.out.println("Reverse triangle:");
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        // printing spaces, 2 at a time from j=1 to j= num-i
        for (int j = 1; j <= (num - i + 1); j++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        //Printing number increamentally from 1 to line number j
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```